# using a JButton actionperformed class how do I add elements from one arraylist to another arraylist?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a  method that returns an arraylist which i am calling via a buttonListener. I need to be able to store each pushes resulting arraylist in another arraylist. How do I do this? Each time i try, it copies over the existing elements in the arraylist I'm using to keep track of push results.

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
public  void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    numCounter++;
    String reqVal1 = requestor.getText();
    int reqVal = Integer.parseInt(reqVal1);
    request = reqVal;
    requestsArray.get(3).set(0,0);
    if(numCounter == 1){//---------------------------numCounter == 1 beginning--------   -------------------------
        workingVar = memSize/2; 
                if(request>workingVar){
                    requestsArray.get(3).set(0,1);
                }
                else{   
           reqCounter++;
    while (workingVar>=request){
        workingVar = workingVar/2;
        holes2.add(workingVar);
    }
    if(workingVar<request){
        workingVar=workingVar*2;
        holes2.add(workingVar);    
        holes2.remove(holes2.size()-2);
        holes2.remove(holes2.size()-1);
            }
    }
    e1=workingVar;
    }//-----------------------------------------------end of numCounter == 1 section-------------------------------------
    if(numCounter > 1){
        for (int y = 0; y<requestsArray.get(0).size();y++){
            if(requestsArray.get(1).get(y).equals("H")){
                holes.add((Integer)requestsArray.get(0).get(y));
            }
        }
        //BubbleSort of holes ArrayList
        int in, out;
        for(out= holes.size()-1; out>0;out--) 
            for(in =0; in<out;in++)
            if(holes.get(in)<holes.get(in+1)){
                int temp1 = holes.get(in+1);
                int temp2 = holes.get(in);
                holes.set(in, temp1);
                holes.set(in+1, temp2);
            }

    //calculates the value of e1 using holes array
        if(holes.isEmpty()){
            requestsArray.get(3).set(0, 1); 
        }
        else{
        for(element=holes.size()-1;element>-1;element--){//starts at end of holes array loops backwards
            e1 = holes.get(element); //assigns value of each element to e1  
         if(e1>=request)    //if value e1 is greater than request stop looping                                                           
            break;                        
            }

    workingVar=e1; //assign the value of e1 to workingVar
    if (request>e1){
        requestsArray.get(3).set(0, 1);                   
    }
    else{
        //---------------------code for populating holes2 array---------------------------
        reqCounter++;
    if(workingVar!=request && workingVar/2>=request){
        while (workingVar/2>=request){
            workingVar = workingVar/2;
            holes2.add(workingVar);
            }     
        if(workingVar<request){
            workingVar=workingVar*2;
            holes2.add(workingVar); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Sort of Holes2 ArrayList - reorder's holes2 for initial set up and subsequent inserts
    int in, out;
    for(out= holes2.size()-1; out>0;out--) 
        for(in =0; in<out;in++)
        if(holes2.get(in)>holes2.get(in+1)){
            int temp1 = holes2.get(in+1);
            int temp2 = holes2.get(in);
            holes2.set(in, temp1);
            holes2.set(in+1, temp2);
        }

   //-------------------------------requestsArray Setups----------------------------------------------------
        //Initial setup of requestsArray 
    if(numCounter == 1){
        if(requestsArray.get(3).get(0).equals(0)){
        requestsArray.get(0).set(0,e1);
        requestsArray.get(1).set(0,"R");
        requestsArray.get(2).set(0, reqCounter);;
        for(int i = 0; i<holes2.size();i++){
            requestsArray.get(0).add(holes2.get(i));
            requestsArray.get(1).add("H");
            requestsArray.get(2).add(0);
            }
        }
        else{
            requestsArray.get(0).set(0,e1);
            requestsArray.get(1).set(0, "H");       
            requestsArray.get(2).set(0,0);
        }
    }

    //Subsequent setup of requestsArray

    int element2;           
    if(numCounter >1 && requestsArray.get(3).get(0).equals(0)){
        for(element2 = 0; element2< requestsArray.get(0).size(); element2++){
            if((Integer)requestsArray.get(0).get(element2)==e1 &&requestsArray.get(1).get(element2).equals("H") ){
                break;
                    }
        }
            if(holes2.isEmpty()){
            requestsArray.get(1).set(element2, "R");
            requestsArray.get(2).set(element2, reqCounter);
                    }
            else{ //holes2 is not empty
                requestsArray.get(0).add(element2, workingVar);
                requestsArray.get(2).add(element2,reqCounter);
                requestsArray.get(1).add(element2, "R");
                requestsArray.get(0).remove(element2+1);
                requestsArray.get(2).remove(element2+1);
                requestsArray.get(1).remove(element2+1);                    
                for(int i = 1; i<holes2.size()+1;i++){
                    requestsArray.get(0).add(element2+i,holes2.get(i-1));
                    requestsArray.get(1).add(element2+i,"H");
                    requestsArray.get(2).add(element2+i,0);
                    }
                }                           
        }


    //-----------------End Section for populating requestsArraywhen numCounter > 1---------------------------           

        //remove all values from holes1 and holes2
        holes.clear();
        holes2.clear();
        System.out.println(results1);
```

ok. I have written a similar program that is simpler and easier to understand. Each time the button is pressed, the result is saved as an arrayList to another arrayList. Problem is it's appending it to the previous element. I need to be able to add the results of each press as a separate element. For example:
first press:
[5, 3, 5, 2, 6, 5]
second press would display:
[5, 3, 5, 2, 6, 5][2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1]
This way I can loop through and get each array result separately. How do I do this?

```
public class mainClass{
        public static void main(String[] args){
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("testButton");
frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame. EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
buttonExample b1 = new buttonExample(); 
frame1.getContentPane().add(b1);
frame1.pack();
frame1.setVisible(true);
            }

    }

    public class Example {
            private int rand1; 
            private ArrayList<ArrayList> count; 
            private ArrayList<Integer> count2;
            private Random rnd;
            private int counter1;
            private ArrayList<ArrayList>count3;
        public Example(){
            count = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
            count2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            rnd = new Random();
            count3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
}
        private void addCount2(){
            for(int x = 0; x<6;x++){
            rand1 = rnd.nextInt(6)+1;
            count2.add(rand1);// count2 == Integers
            }
        }

        public void addCount(){
            addCount2();
            count.add(count2);// count == count3
        }
        public ArrayList<ArrayList> displayCount(){
        return count;   

        }
}

public class buttonExample extends JPanel {
private JButton button1;
private Example example1;
public buttonExample(){
button1 = new JButton("Submit");
add(button1);
button1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
example1 = new Example();
}
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    example1.addCount();
    System.out.println(example1.displayCount().get(0));;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You'd have to provide the critical part of your code, so we can see what's actually happening.

Comment: Post a sample of what you have done and where you are facing difficualty, then it is easier to help you out

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

I would think about at least two solutions...

1. create a `List<...> list` which will last (global variable or something similar, depends on your needs) and use `list.addAll()` method
2. create a `Map<String, List<...> map` and than you can log your lists separately, your key might be a timestamp for example

Well, now when you posted the code you will have to start with a different thing - refactoring. Your code is very long, difficult to read and error prone. You have to think about it a little bit a rewrite it. And trust me, the more effort you put into your code at the beginning the better it will be at the end. Otherwise you may end up with an unmanagable code full of bugs...

Comment: added results1 as global variable and  results1.addAll(requestsArray); but all elements in results1 array were copied over by the most recent element added.

Comment: @user1888433 If you want us to help you, you will have to do what we say. Andrew told you to post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so please do it. I really don't know what your code does...

Comment: Added more simplified example. Hope this helps. I am really struggling here for some reason.  Thanks!!